# SVN - Branched tag back to root

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, branch, tags

I have a svn repository. I have now created a branch for this repository to do some major dev work. Now some of the features that I can created in my project can be committed directly to the main repository instead of the branch. Is there a way to do commit those changes without having me to switch the branch again?

**Update:**

I am using TortoiseSVN and was hoping to use that to re-integrate the branch back into the root.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to switch back to trunk, or checkout a new working copy. You can have 2 or more working copies based on different URLs/branches.

Then use reintegrate merge if you want to close the branch (useful for a feature branch when the feature is done), or normal merge if you want to continue development on the branch.

See [merging with TortoiseSvn](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like maybe `svn merge --reintegrate` is what you're looking for?

http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn.branchmerge.basicmerging.html

Comment: I am using tortoiseSVN (I updated my post). Can I use that somehow to re-integrate?

Answer (score 1):

You needs to re-integrate the branch with the trunk (root).

Check on [this link](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-dug-merge.html) on section **Reintegrate a branch** of the Tortoise SVN online help.